# Choosing document models in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Which of these document models would be better to use in MongoDB?

```
Animal:
{
    _id: "1",
    name: "abc",
    locations_spotted: [
      {
        locId: "1",
        dates: ["1-1-2009", "12-4-2013"...]
      },
      {
        locId: "2",
        dates: ["3-1-2012", "12-3-2013"...]
      }
      ...
    ]
}

Animal:
{
    _id: "1",
    name: "abc",
    loc1spotdates: ["1-1-2009", "12-4-2013"...],
    loc2spotdates: ["3-1-2012", "12-3-2013"...],
    ...
    ...
}
```

There are a limited number of locations and only a few might get added in the future.

Comment: the schema here would depend on how you would use the data in future.

Comment: I would mostly be querying for spotted dates of Animal object

Comment: you should try second option as it would give you easy access to both data: location as well as querying by date.

Answer (score 0):

First variant is better in my opinion. Because in future if you prefer to add additional information you add it right into the object inside array. You leave your options open. In future you could add time of the day also maybe.